# SharePlum - Sharepoint List - Delete Records

Tags: python, sharepoint

All,

I have written a python script to delete rows based on some condition ( note i'm not looking for deleting all the rows) from the sharepoint list using python-shareplum package.

My Code snippet as below:

```
Begin_Date= pd.datetime(date.today().year, date.today().month, 1)
new_list = site.List('IRC Reporting (Tableau) - IRC PNL History Data')
fields = ['IRC Approval Date','Demand Region','Product Category']
query = {'Where': [('Eq', 'IRC Approval Date', Begin_Date)]}
dt =  [row['IRC Approval Date'] for row in new_list.GetListItems(fields=fields,query=query)]
new_list.UpdateListItems(dt, 'Delete')
print(dev_ids)
```

the script is running fine,but the records are not deleted from the list.

Inputs are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the list items by passing list item ID to the UpdateListItems in Shareplum. Below code works if your list is less than or equals to 5000.

```
from shareplum import Office365,Site
from shareplum.site import Version
Begin_Date= pd.datetime(date.today().year, date.today().month, 1)    
authcookie = Office365(server_url, username = Username, 
password=Password).GetCookies()
site = Site(site_url, version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
sp_list = site.List('IRC Reporting (Tableau) - IRC PNL History Data')
fields=['ID']
query = {'Where': [('Eq', 'IRC Approval Date', Begin_Date)]}
sp_data =sp_list.GetListItems(fields=fields,query=query)
del_df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sp_data)
list_data = del_df['ID'].tolist()
sp_list.UpdateListItems(data=list_data,kind='Delete')
```